# Mysql index of hash table

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

TABLE-A contains 50 million records containing one field of hashed data.
TABLE-B contains 15 thousand rows of hashed data.
I'd like to check to see if each record in TABLE-B in is TABLE-A.

How should TABLE-A be indexed to speed up the search?

Comment: index whichever fields you are searching?

Answer (score 0):

Initially my though was that the hash is already unique and my better bet was to index TABLE-B and use TABLE-A rows to initiate the search, but ultimately I did index TABLE-A on the first 5 characters and it helped tremendously.